# ngx-datatable column toggle show/hide issue

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have used ngx-datatable column toggle function to show/hide columsn. I have a column which has check box should not get affected while using toggle function but For my case it is disappeared. How to fix this issue.

Below is the html code used

```
 <ngx-datatable>      
  <ngx-datatable-column [width]="30" [resizeable]="false" [sortable]="false" [draggable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false" [name]='chkBox'>
       <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-value="value" let-allRowsSelected="allRowsSelected"
          let-selectFn="selectFn">
          <input type="checkbox" [checked]="allRowsSelected" (change)="selectFn(!allRowsSelected)" />
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value" let-isSelected="isSelected"
          let-onCheckboxChangeFn="onCheckboxChangeFn">
          <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected" (change)="onCheckboxChangeFn($event)" />
        </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
   <ngx-datatable-column prop="itemType" [name]='"Item Type"| translate'>
        <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{value}}
        </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
   <ngx-datatable-column prop="itemId" [name]='"Item ID" | translate'>
        <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{value}}
        </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
   <ngx-datatable-column prop="itemName" [name]='"Item Name"| translate'>
        <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{value}}
        </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
 </ngx-datatable>
```

below is the code used to show hide coluumns

```
<div class='selected-column'>
  <h4>Available Columns</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor='let col of allColumns'>
      <input *ngIf="col.name!='chkBox'" 
        type='checkbox'
        [id]="col.name"
        (click)='toggle(col)'
        [checked]='isChecked(col)'
      />
      <label [attr.for]="col.name">{{col.name}}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

toggle(col) {
if (col.name != "chkBox") {
  const isChecked = this.isChecked(col);
  if (isChecked) {
    this.columns = this.columns.filter(c => {
      return c.name !== col.name;
    });
  } else {
    const newColumns = [...this.columns, col];
    this.columns = [];
    this.allColumns.forEach((f) => {
      newColumns.forEach((s) => {
        if (s.name === f.name) {
          this.columns.push(f);
        }
      });
    });
  }
 } 
}
isChecked(col) {
return this.columns.find(c => {
  return c.name === col.name;
});}
```

I don't want to hide the first column (chkBox) in show/hide toggle function in ngx-datatable. How to achieve this?